# Java Socket Message isn't readable after file tranfer

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

I sent a File from one Socket to an other. After this I try to sent a simple message but this doesn't work. Can someone tell why?

Sent File and Message:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
int len = 0;
while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
client.shutdownOutput();

//Following doesnt work:
PrintWriter m_out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
m_out.println("anfrage erhalten");
m_out.flush();
```

Receive File and Message:

```
File pdfFile = new File("marke.pdf");
OutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);

OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
int len = 0;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fs.write(buffer, 0, len);
}   
fs.flush();
fs.close();
client.shutdownOutput();

// Here i will receive the Message after the file transfer, but this doesnt work!
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Comment: What exactly does not work, any exceptions? I guess you closed the client socket in `clinet.shutdownOutput()`, but it's only a guess...

Comment: here: System.out.println(br.readLine());
i should receivey the message "Anfrage erhalten". but there is only NULL and no Data. Without the shutdown is the same, this was only a tipp from anywhere to fix my problem, but it doesnt work. If i send the message befor i transfer the file, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing a message toy the output stream after having shut down the output. You should get an IOException by doing it.

Moreover, you're using the same stream to write textual data after having written some binary data. If you do this, you have to find a way at the other side to know where the binary data ends, and when the textual data begins. If you read bytes until the end of the stream like you're doing, you will read the binary data concatenated with the bytes of the textual data.

Comment: You need to define a dedicated protocol. One way would be to write the length of the binary data, then the binary data, then the textual data. When reading, you would first read the length (n), then read the binary data (n bytes), then read the textual data. DataOutputStream and DataInputStream might help.

Comment: Thank you, did you know a website or something where i can find an example or an tutorial for these things?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html